# Strange regex behavior in VS2012 C++

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

This code snippet:

```
smatch m;
auto   a = regex_search ("uyiu #23->45 kjlk",    regex ("->"));
auto   b = regex_match  ("uyiu #23->45 kjlk", m, regex ("->"));

cout << a << " " << b;
```

produces (in VS2012 C++):

```
1 0
```

and `m` is empty. Why not `1 1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From regex_match's documentation:

**The entire target sequence** must match the regular expression for this function to return true.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/

Comment: `match/search distinction` Nope. JS and .NET are 2 examples. And Python's match does force the match to start from the beginning of the string, but it does not force the match to end at the end of the string...

Comment: @Patashu Thank you. Also your link is more readable than the one I started with.